# req.cookies is null and I don't know why

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I've looked at a few previous stack overflow posts but can't figure out why this is happening.

I have included cookie parser before all my routes and the cookie is in the browser. For some reason I just can't access it.

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const AppError = require("./utils/appError");
const globalErrorHandler = require("./controllers/errorController");
const dishRouter = require("./routes/dishRoutes");
const userRouter = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const orderRouter = require("./routes/orderRoutes");
const imageRouter = require("./routes/imageRouter");

const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.options("*", cors());
```

ROUTES...

Here is how I am accessing the req.cookies

First I do an axios call

```
axios({
      method: "patch",
      url: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/me`,
      data: this.state,
    })
```

Then it goes through this middleware

```
router
  .route("/me")
  .patch(authController.protect, userController.updateProfile)
```

In authController.protect I do the following

```
try {
    //1) Getting token and check if it exists.
    let token;
    if (
      //POSTMAN
      req.headers.authorization &&
      req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
    ) {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    } else if (req.cookies.jwt) {
      token = req.cookies.jwt;
    }
    console.log(`TOKEN: ${token}`);
    console.log(req.cookies);
```

The console.log right above gives null.

[image: Cookie browser proof]

Comment: Edited the post for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced a similar issue with my code where I was getting null when checking req.cookies. I used express for my node.js files and I followed the explanations from the following links:

- http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

So from server side I added configuration to `cors()` and set `credentials: true` and on client side from my `fetch()` request I added `credentials: 'include'` and this gave me access to the cookies on my browser. My `fetch()` request was making use of the PUT method.

Comment: Had something similar. It was because I didn't add withCredentials: true in my axios calls. I tried answering my own question but someone deleted it I don't know why. Thanks for reaching out :)